# Unity - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm having issues implementing Google Play Games Services. Building always fails with this error, please help!

> Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package
>   resources. See the Console for details.
>   C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe
>   package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   "res" -I
>   "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-20\android.jar"
>   -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj -S
>   "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res"
>
> stderr[
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
>
> ] stdout[ Configurations: (default) v11 v21 mdpi-v4 tvdpi-v4 hdpi-v4
>   xhdpi-v4 xxhdpi-v4 xxxhdpi-v4 ca da fa ja nb de af bg th fi hi vi sk
>   uk el nl pl sl tl am in ko ro ar fr hr sr tr cs es it lt pt hu ru zu
>   lv sv iw sw fr-CA lo-LA en-GB bn-BD et-EE ka-GE ky-KG km-KH zh-HK
>   si-LK mk-MK ur-PK sq-AL hy-AM my-MM zh-CN pa-IN ta-IN te-IN ml-IN
>   en-IN kn-IN mr-IN gu-IN mn-MN ne-NP pt-BR gl-ES eu-ES is-IS es-US
>   pt-PT en-AU zh-TW ms-MY az-AZ kk-KZ uz-UZ
>
> Files: color\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\color\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
>   color\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\color\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
>   color\common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\color\common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
>   color\common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\color\common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml
>   color\wallet_primary_text_holo_light.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\color\wallet_primary_text_holo_light.xml
>   color\wallet_secondary_text_holo_dark.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\color\wallet_secondary_text_holo_dark.xml
>   drawable\cast_ic_notification_0.png Src: (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\cast_ic_notification_0.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\cast_ic_notification_0.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\cast_ic_notification_0.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\cast_ic_notification_0.png
>   drawable\cast_ic_notification_1.png Src: (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\cast_ic_notification_1.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\cast_ic_notification_1.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\cast_ic_notification_1.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\cast_ic_notification_1.png
>   drawable\cast_ic_notification_2.png Src: (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\cast_ic_notification_2.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\cast_ic_notification_2.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\cast_ic_notification_2.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\cast_ic_notification_2.png
>   drawable\cast_ic_notification_connecting.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable\cast_ic_notification_connecting.xml
>   drawable\cast_ic_notification_on.png Src: (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\cast_ic_notification_on.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\cast_ic_notification_on.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\cast_ic_notification_on.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\cast_ic_notification_on.png
>   drawable\common_full_open_on_phone.png Src: (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml Src: ()
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
>   drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png Src:
>   (mdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (tvdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (hdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (xhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
>   Src: (xxhdpi-v4)
>   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Orbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
>   drawable\c

Comment: Few suggestions, - update your sdk, look for the duplicate files that might be any JAR file or `res` folder, verify your android manifest.

Comment: Looks like 2 issues, first your Android SDK should be updated to the latest.  This handles the resource not found issue.  Second,  there are duplicate libraries in Assets/Plugins/Android most likely culprit is google-play-services_lib.  Try to delete that and rebuild.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By updating my Android SDK and reinstalling the GPGS plugin, I got it working :)

Thanks @Clayton Wilkison and @Hamza Hasan